# My back office prestashop are broken after migrating to another server

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, migrate

I just migrate my prestashop site from development server to production server. The front end works well, however the back end are broken such as the submenu not appear, some buttons not working, some css seems broken. It cannot work as back office.

I already transfer all files to the server. I don't have any idea what is the problem.

May I know how to fix this problem?

Comment: did you check console errors, PHP errors log ? without this it s hard to help you

Comment: It is, possibly, maybe a problem with PHP version on your production server. For 1.6* version are recommended versions of PHP not higher than 5.6 and your server probably has PHP 7+. If it is so, try to lower down your server PHP version

Comment: some of the files are being left behind while transfering..